# Artisan won't make migration without sudo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Hopefully this is a real simple one. I'm just doing the Laravel quickstart tutorial from their site (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) and it says to enter `php artisan make:migration create_tasks_table --create=tasks` to create a migration.

It doesn't want to make the migration file unless I sudo it, which a) it complains about, and b) I now have to enter my password every time I edit the file. Without sudo it doesn't throw an error or really do anything...

This can't be correct - is there something I'm doing obviously wrong here?

Comment: what `it complains about [sudo]` really means?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of your migrations directory?